# User defined function gives error "Invalid qualifier"

Tags: excel, vba

`studgrd` means student grade
`mrk` means Marks
`res` means result

```
Function studgrd(mrk As Long) As String   
Dim res As String    
res.Formula = "=if(mrk>=90,""A"",if(mrk>=70,""B"",if(mrk>=60,""C"",if(mrk>=50,""d"",""Fail""))))"    
studgrd = res    
End Function
```

Comment: `res.Formula` doesn't make sense because a `String` does not have a `Formula` property. It might be easier to use `Select Case` here, rather than your current attempt, i.e. `Select Case True`, `Case mrk >=90`, and so on.

Comment: BigBen-- thank you sir. I am new to VBA and trying to learn it. Didn't know about that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat `mrk` as a variable rather than part of a string:

```
Function studgrd(mrk As Long) As String
    Dim res As String
    res = Evaluate("=if(" & mrk & ">=90,""A"",if(" & mrk & ">=70,""B"",if(" & mrk & ">=60,""C"",if(" & mrk & ">=50,""d"",""Fail""))))")
    studgrd = res
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I pasted code same as yours but it is giving me error- function call on left-hand side of assignment must return vairant or object.

Comment: @SumitSingh  Are you using the UDF in a worksheet cell or in another macro??

Comment: Gary's Student:- code is working perfectly. I changed the function name and forgot to change its name in the below section. LOL   Could you please explain to me what is evaluate and why you have added space with mark using &

Comment: @SumitSingh  `EVALUATE()` takes a formula in String format and evaluates it just like in a cell.  In my example, I give the UDF *80*.  The UDF evaluates:  `=if(80>=90,"A",if(80>=70,"B",if(80>=60,"C",if(80>=50,"d","Fail"))))`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a really nice opportunity to try out the VBA Switch function!

```
Function StudentGrade(mark As Long) As String
    StudentGrade = Switch(mark >= 90, "A", mark >= 70, "B", mark >= 60, "C", _
                          mark >= 50, "D", mark < 50, "Fail")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's great. Code is working perfectly and it is short also.

Answer (score 0):

### In the 'Spirit of VBA'

**Compare `Select Case` and `ElseIf`**

```
Option Explicit

Function studgrdSelectCase(mrk As Long) As String
    Select Case mrk
        Case Is >= 90
            studgrdSelectCase = "A"
        Case Is >= 70
            studgrdSelectCase = "B"
        Case Is >= 60
            studgrdSelectCase = "C"
        Case Is >= 50
            studgrdSelectCase = "D"
        Case Else
            studgrdSelectCase = "Fail"
    End Select
End Function

Function studgrdElseIf(mrk As Long) As String
    If mrk >= 90 Then
        studgrdElseIf = "A"
    ElseIf mrk >= 70 Then
        studgrdElseIf = "B"
    ElseIf mrk >= 60 Then
        studgrdElseIf = "C"
    ElseIf mrk >= 50 Then
        studgrdElseIf = "D"
    Else
        studgrdElseIf = "Fail"
    End If
End Function
```

**Performance**

- **Benchmarking** on my machine showed for up to one million code executions that these two approaches are roughly equally efficient. They are about 5 times faster than the `Switch` version and more than 150 times faster than the `Evaluate` version (0.25s, 1.3s, 41s).
- **In practice** the 'lag of recalculation' will 'get' you long before that i.e. copying a cell containing any version to 10,000 rows will take over 12 seconds to recalculate. (copying to 1,000 rows will take less than a second). It is a one-time wait though.
- It's safe to conclude that any of the versions will do.

**Excel**

- Why use VBA when a simple formula can handle this more efficiently?

  ```
  =IF(A2>=90,"A",IF(A2>=80,"B",IF(A2>=60,"C",IF(A2>=50,"D","Fail"))))
  ```
- Copying this formula 10,000 rows down takes a split second to recalculate.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am learning vba  therefore I was experimenting can I find out the answer using the above code which i posted.

Comment: #VBasic2008,  wow sir, you are so knowledgeable. I acknowledge you and wish to learn vba from you. Both codes are working perfectly. Thank you so much